# Extract dataframe from dataframe based on column value with extended bounds

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| NAME | SIGNAL |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0 |
| b | 0 |
| c | 0 |
| d | 0 |
| e | 1 |
| f | 1 |
| g | 1 |
| h | 0 |
| i | 0 |
| j | 0 |
| k | 0 |
| l | 0 |
| m | 0 |
| n | 1 |
| o | 1 |
| p | 1 |
| q | 1 |
| r | 0 |
| s | 0 |
| t | 0 |

I need to write a function that will allow me to extract another dataframe, or just modify the existing frame based on a condition:

Get all columns (in my case NAME) if  SIGNAL column is 1 for the row but also extract 2 rows extra from above and 2 rows extra from bellow.

In my example, the function should return me the following table:

| NAME | SIGNAL |
| --- | --- |
| c | 0 |
| d | 0 |
| e | 1 |
| f | 1 |
| g | 1 |
| h | 0 |
| i | 0 |
| j | 0 |
| l | 0 |
| m | 0 |
| n | 1 |
| o | 1 |
| p | 1 |
| q | 1 |
| r | 0 |
| s | 0 |

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is the code I have so far:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['a', 0], ['b', 0], ['c', 1], ['d', 1], ['e', 0], ['f', 0], ['g', 0], ['h', 1], ['i', 0], ['j', 0], ['k', 0]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NAME', 'SIGNAL'])
 
# print dataframe.
print(df)


print("----------------")
      
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row['Name'], row['Age'])

    if((df.iloc[index]['SIGNAL'] == 1) & (df.iloc[index-1]['SIGNAL'] == 0)): #check when the signal change from 0 to 1
        print(df.iloc[index]['NAME']) #first line with signal 1 after it was 0

        #print the above 2 lines
        print(df.iloc[index-1]['NAME'])
        print(df.iloc[index-2]['NAME'])
```

My dataframe is like:

```
   NAME  SIGNAL
0     a       0
1     b       0
2     c       1
3     d       1
4     e       0
5     f       0
6     g       0
7     h       1
8     i       0
9     j       0
10    k       0
```

My code is returning:

```
c
b
a
h
g
f
```

The problem here is that I cannot return the value of "d" and "e" + "f" or "i" and "j" because i get the error "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" if i try if condition:

```
(df.iloc[index]['SIGNAL'] == 1) & (df.iloc[index+1]['SIGNAL'] == 0)

enter code here
```

Also the extended bounds will be variable, sometimes I will work with 2 extra rows from top and bottom sometimes with more.

I am looking for a solution using dataframes functions and not iteration.

thanks!

Comment: 1) Why is `j` being returned in your output, it's 3 away from the nearest `1` in `signal` 2) Please post sample data in the text of your question, not as a picture, so that we can copy and paste it 3) What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please include _code_ as part of your [mcve]

Comment: sorry, the J being in the result is a mistake. I will update soon the question with code. thanks!

Comment: @G.Anderson I made an example and i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the desired data frame:

```
df[(df.shift(periods=-2, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1) | (df.shift(periods=-1, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1) | (df.SIGNAL == 1) | (df.shift(periods=1, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1) | (df.shift(periods=2, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1)]
```

**Output:**

| NAME | SIGNAL |
| --- | --- |
| c | 0 |
| d | 0 |
| e | 1 |
| f | 1 |
| g | 1 |
| h | 0 |
| i | 0 |
| l | 0 |
| m | 0 |
| n | 1 |
| o | 1 |
| p | 1 |
| q | 1 |
| r | 0 |
| s | 0 |

Add `.NAME` to the end to get your series of names

```
2     c
3     d
4     e
5     f
6     g
7     h
8     i
11    l
12    m
13    n
14    o
15    p
16    q
17    r
18    s
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

---

**Update:** for arbitrarily large span

```
m=(df.shift(periods=-400, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1)

for i in list(range(-399,401)):
    m= m | (df.shift(periods=i, axis="rows").SIGNAL == 1)
print(df[m])
```

### **Disclaimer:**

This method may be inefficient for large spans

Comment: thanks, seams like working. if i have a another column with a date it looks like the function is not keeping the order even if after that i add.sort_values('DATE'), but i will find myself a solution for the sorting issue. Do you mind to explain what the "|" is doing?

Comment: In python "|"  is the  bitwise operator version of `or`. It is the counterpart of "&". Basically it is saying, "take the union of theses series".

Comment: can i make this work for 400 rows above and 400 rows bellow instead of 2? i tried to adjust periods value but didnt worked.

Comment: @Lapoco, the update should answer your question. Keep in mind that this method is likely to be relativly slow for your stated purpose, but feel free to test it out.